# Optimizing code for calculating the best move for Animal Java

Tags: java, optimization

```
/**
 * 
 * @param listOfEntities - The list to be checked
 * @param entity - The entity to base the searching off of.
 * @return - the Point of the highest scoring goal
 * 
 * TODO: Make this code better, it relies too much on instanceof and is not OOP.
 *       
 */
protected Point getBestMove(List<Point> listOfEntities,Entity entity) {
    //Store the position of the highest valued prey.
    Point highestScore = null;

    // Check if the entity passed in is a Sheep, if it is
    // then loop through the map within the line of sight
    // of this animal and then score individually.
    // Based on the result move in a direction that is benifitial.
    if (entity instanceof Sheep) {
        // The scoring map using a Point, Double system.
        Map<Point, Double> bestMoveMap = new HashMap<>();

        //Loop through for every entity position in listOfEntities
        for(Point currentEntity : listOfEntities) {
            //Put this current entity with a basevalue of 2400.
            bestMoveMap.put(currentEntity, 2400.0);

            // Loop X and Y within line of sight (- since we want both directions)
            for (int xPos = - lineOfSight; xPos <= lineOfSight; xPos++) {
                for (int yPos = - lineOfSight; yPos <= lineOfSight; yPos++) {
                    // Get the starting point of this entity
                    double points = bestMoveMap.get(currentEntity);

                    // Get the distance between this entity and the goal entity.
                    Point goalPoint = new Point(currentEntity.x + xPos,currentEntity.y + yPos);

                    // Store all entities in a list within range.
                    List<Entity> entities = pasture.getGrid().get(goalPoint);

                    //If list is not empty or null
                    if(entities != null && entities.isEmpty() == false) {
                        //Loop through all the entities
                        for(Entity e : entities) {
                            //If it is a wolf.
                            if(e instanceof Wolf) {
                                //Score depending on distance using a formula.
                                double distanceToWolf = goalPoint.distance(currentEntity);

                                // Calculate using a formula where we factor in the distance to the wolf.
                                points = points + (1000 / (1 + distanceToWolf));

                                // Put this entity with the position.
                                bestMoveMap.put(currentEntity, points);
                            }
                            // If it is a plant.
                            if(e instanceof Plant) {
                                //Score depending on distance using a formula.
                                double distanceToPlant = goalPoint.distance(currentEntity);

                                points = points - (100 / (1 + distanceToPlant));
                                bestMoveMap.put(currentEntity, points);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }            
            }}

        //Minimum score.
        Map.Entry<Point, Double> minScore = null;

        // Get the highest scored value and set minScore aswell as highestScore.
        // Since Java 8 you could do this:
        // Collections.max(bestMoveMap.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();
        for (Map.Entry<Point, Double> entry : bestMoveMap.entrySet()){
            if (minScore == null || minScore.getValue() > entry.getValue()){
                // Set highestScore to that and minScore to that entry.
                minScore = entry;
                highestScore= minScore.getKey();
            }
        }
    }
    // If the entity is a Wolf
    if(entity instanceof Wolf){
        Map<Point, Double> bestMoveMap = new HashMap<>();
        for(Point thisPoint : listOfEntities){
            bestMoveMap.put(thisPoint, 2000.0);

            for (int x = -lineOfSight; x <= lineOfSight; x++) {
                for (int y = -lineOfSight; y <= lineOfSight; y++) {
                    Point p = new Point(thisPoint.x + x,thisPoint.y + y);
                    List<Entity> l =pasture.getGrid().get(p);
                    if(l!=null){
                        for(Entity e:l){

                            //Only interested in Sheeps
                            if(e instanceof Sheep){
                                double distanceToSheep=p.distance(thisPoint);
                                double points=bestMoveMap.get(thisPoint);
                                points = points -(10000/(0.1+distanceToSheep));
                                bestMoveMap.put(thisPoint, points);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Set highestScore to the best Point.
        Map.Entry<Point, Double> min = null;
        for(Map.Entry<Point, Double> entry : bestMoveMap.entrySet()) {
            if (min == null || min.getValue() > entry.getValue()) {
                min = entry;
                highestScore= min.getKey();
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the highest score, the Point that scored the highest
    return highestScore;
}
```

I got this code above which finds the best new Point for an Animal. The basic idea is:

Sheeps eats grass and avoids Wolves
Wolves hunt Sheeps and has no enemies

It is pretty long and I was wondering if there is any way I could shorten or improve it? I feel as if the "instanceof" is a bad habit but I am not sure how to do it otherwise or what to replace it with. Especially since the code is so similar in many aspects. Maybe I can combine it in some way?

Comment: I found a improvement after posting, the distance I made a variable in the beginning instead of a separate one for each loop (double distance).

Answer (score 0):

The way to avoid `instanceof` is to move functionality into classes and make use of inheritance and polymorphism.

So, instead of `if( e instanceof Wolf ) { do wolfy stuff... } else if( e instanceof Plant ) { do plant stuff... }` you would invoke `e.doStuff()`.

Then, the `Wolf` entity would have an implementation of `doStuff()` which does wolfy stuff, while the `Plant` entity would have its own implementation of `doStuff()` which does plant stuff.

Of course the base class `Entity` would declare a `public abstract doStuff();` so that `Wolf` and `Plant` can override it.